# How to rectify and smooth a high frequency sinewave

Tags: high-frequency, bridge-rectifier, electrolytic-capacitor

I'm working on an experiment that generates a high frequency sinewave using an air core transformer.

How can I rectify and smoothen this high frequency sinewave because most of the high current rectifiers and electrolytic capacitors sold online are for low frequency signals?

The frequency range of the generator is between 5KHz to 20KHz.

Also what is frequency range of the common rectifiers and electrolytic capacitors?

Thanks.

Comment: How much current? How much capacitance?

Comment: Do you mean current of the generator? When upscaled, it will be around 50amps

Comment: I forgot to ask, how much is the voltage?

Comment: Voltage is around 48V

Answer (score 3):

> *How can I rectify and smoothen this high frequency sinewave because
> most of the high current rectifiers and electrolytic capacitors sold
> online are for low frequency signals?*

Use fast diodes and capacitors that are rated for tens of kHz ripple current.

There are plenty to choose from. You might also consider Schottky diodes because they have zero reverse recovery time (as opposed to the ubiquitous 1N400x which can be as high as 30 μs from some suppliers).

There are plenty of electrolytic capacitors that have ripple current ratings for 100 kHz.

> *Also what is frequency range of the common rectifiers and electrolytic
> capacitors?*

How long is a piece of string - you point out a capacitor and add a link to its data sheet and it will rapidly become apparent.

Comment: Do be aware of the high reverse leakage of Schottky diodes, though. FREDs are an option if you need low leakage and high speed.

Comment: Where can I get this fast diodes and capacitors? I mostly shop from AliExpress but I couldn't find it there.

Comment: Farnell, Digikey, Mouser and RS and the common favourites for pros in the UK and most other places. I wouldn't buy components from (M)ali-express for a [golden pig](https://www.amazon.com/golden-pig/s?k=golden+pig) especially if it came from Shamazon. Pros buy from reputable sources for good reasons.

Comment: Aliexpress is just about the worst source you could get electronic components from. Seconding Andy's recommendations, with the addendum that Farnell goes by the name Newark in at least North America, and possibly other parts of the world too.

Comment: Thanks. Do they ship their products outside the country? I am currently in Nigeria. I'm new to electronics but I'm really enthusiastic about it.

Comment: @Daenny that's your job to find out - contact them.

Comment: @Daenny if we are done with this Q and A session now you should consider accepting my answer or, if you need further clarification, leave a comment. [Answer accepting button shown in this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).